# how to watch a date object in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to watch a date in angularJS ?
I have an ng-model that contains a date and i want to watch it so when it change of month,year or day i got a notification.

```
scope.$watch('ngModel',function(newVal){
    console.log(newVal);
  },true);
```

I have a controller where i give a date object to a directive.
And now i want to watch that date object.

```
module.directive('Datepicker',function(){
return {
 restrict:'E',
 scope:{
   ngModel:"="
 },
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    //..other code here
    scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal) {
        console.log(ngModel);
    }, true);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: use the model name instead NgModel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are in directive then you should use `attrs.ngModel` instead of `ngModel` only, it should be inside link/compile function of directive

**Code**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'E',
        scope: { ngModel: '='},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            //..other code here
            scope.$watch('$parent.'+ attrs.ngModel, function(newVal) {
                console.log(newVal);
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @user3093036 could you share your more directive code? are you using isolated scope?

Comment: i indeed use an isolated scope but your example works but that watch returns an atrr object ?

Comment: @user3093036 please add code, I can't predict what is going on in your code, give a try by doing `'$parent.'+ attrs.ngModel`

Comment: @user3093036 `.` was missing `$parent.`, take a look at update

Answer (score -1):

you ngModel should be available as $scope:

```
function myController($scope){
   $scope.today = new Date()
      $scope.$watch('today',function(newVal,oldVal){
         //code goes here
      },true)
}
```

Comment: is the value actually getting to the controller?